# Sum of LS-LMSR probabilities is greater than 1

Tags: finance, markets, theory

I am trying to implement LS-LMSR in a prediction market with binary outcomes: YES and NO. I am implementing this formula as the cost:

[image]

```
Alpha: 0.1
Q1 shares: 1
Q2 shares: 0
```

When I "buy" one more share of Q1 given the market above, `C(2, 0) - C(1, 0)`, the probability spikes up to `1.0000045398899218`. How can the probability be greater than 100% and why is this so volatile? This makes no sense as why would people buy more shares of Q1 if after 1 share is bought, the value jumps so high? Am I implementing the formula wrong? Thanks and feel free to ask if any questions.

Comment: What software are you using to implement this formula?

Comment: @Giskard I am writing it in Python. I am fairly certain that my implementation is correct as I have checked it with example values I found online. I am just struggling to interpret the results of LS-LMSR in the context of a prediction market.